# What CPU model is used for Azure App Service P1V3 tier?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Since there's no official documentation on where to find the CPU specs for Azure App Services, I accessed my existing app service via Kudu and find the following details:

- NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS = 2
- PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE = AMD64
- PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER = Intel64 Family 6 Model 85 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel

I’ve searched various forums and stumble upon six different CPU models using the same identifier above:

- Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8272CL CPU @ 2.60GHz
- Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-10980XE CPU @ 3.00GHz
- Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8275CL CPU @ 3.00GHz
- Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6248 CPU @ 2.50GHz
- DO-Premium-Intel
- Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU @ 2.20GHz

I am just wondering what CPU model is being used using the P1V3 tier.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a cloud offering, Microsoft doesn't make guarantees as of the exact processor type. They may build out racks using Intel Xeon one month, then switch to an AMD offering the next month. That's why they've arrived at a metric called ACU units. It's a guarantee of power, but the actual processor is abstracted away and shouldn't matter.